# How to share PDF file to drop box using Xamarin Android?

Tags: android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am implementing the app with below features.

1. The PDF file will be downloaded in button click
2. Once PDF downloaded the dropbox icon will be enabled
3. When click dropbox icon the dropbox app should be launched with downloaded PDF file to add.

The first 2 items are implemented properly. In 3rd item the dropbox is launching properly using below code. But the downloaded file is not showed in dropbox. can anyone suggest your ideas to achieve this?

```
var pathFile = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
var absolutePath = pathFile.AbsolutePath;
var m_documentMobiNames = "test.pdf";
var mobileFileName = Path.Combine(absolutePath, m_documentMobiNames);
Context context = MainActivity.Active.BaseContext;
Intent sendIntent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.dropbox.android");
sendIntent.SetType("application/pdf");
sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mobileFileName));
context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sendIntent, "Upload file"));
```

Comment: Must  open the .pdf file with dropbox ? If not, you can use intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + mobileFileName), "application/pdf") to pop up a list of app that can open the .pdf file. Then the user can choose dropbox to open the file.